# Drag and Drop SWT TableColumn Headers?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, tableheader

I would like to add drag functionality to Table Headers within the eclipse rcp framework. As far as I have been able to tell there's no support for it at all within SWT if there is great, can someone tell me how?

If not then I am wondering if there's a way to simulate it, ie detect the drag action on the header and force the Drag in to whatever service manages the functionality. Ideally I'd like to see the column getting dragged along next to the cursor, but just a change of cursor would be OK.

This is working towards an application that lets users pick columns from a table and while I have a working application, drag and drop would be the hundreds and thousands on the icing on the cake, but I just can't fathom it.

Comment: Do you want to drag/drop it anywhere in your application or do you need this functionality to change the order of your columns inside your table?

Comment: Column Order Drag/Drop is on by default in SWT tables. I need to be able to drop it on to another component that can detect it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is default support to enable drag and drop of Table column into another component. You have to use Drag and Drop support in SWT to handle this.

Please follow below article to add drag and drop support

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't make a DragSource using a TableColumn though so this won't work.